# Замена части динамической строки

Tags: javascript

Я получаю строку в таком формате `"/program/527/variant/sent"` (это url)
Мне нужно менять число на друго в данном случае `527`.  Вместо `program` может быть другое значение другой длинны.  Но ID (527) в целом всегда идет после.  Как я ее могу динамически вырезать и вставлять другое значение. Или пересобирать строку с другим значением?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let str = "/program/527/variant/sent";
let parts = str.split("/");
parts[2] = 999;
let str1 = parts.join("/");
console.log(str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const src = "/post/527/variant/sent";
const id = 1337;

const dst = src.replace(/^\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/, `/$1/${id}`);

console.log(dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так (замена числа на 1000):

```js
const str1 = "/program/527/variant/sent";

const str2 = str1.replace(/(?<=^\/.+?\/)\d+/, 1000);

console.log(str2);
```